# Properly deserializing a nested JSON feed with NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, ios6

I have a pretty simple problem which i suppose someone with experience would easily be able to answer. There is a JSON feed which delivers video URL content to one of the apps im building. It looks like this:

```
    {
    "playlist": [
        {
            "videos": {
                "ds900": {
                    "length": 30,
                    "bitrate": "900",
                    "uri": "http://somevideo1.mp4"
                },
                "ds300": {
                    "length": 30,
                    "bitrate": "300",
                    "uri": "http://somevideo2.mp4"
                },
                "ds500": {
                    "length": 30,
                    "bitrate": "500",
                    "uri": "http://somevideo3.mp4"
                },
                "ds700": {
                    "length": 30,
                    "bitrate": "700",
                    "uri": "http://somevideo4.mp4"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "playlistName": "The Play List Name",
    "description": "The description"
}
```

To deserialize this i have the following code:

```
    -(void)connectToVideoLink
{
    NSString *urlString = @"http://Link_To_JSON_feed";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest =
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                 timeoutInterval:30.0f];


    NSOperationQueue *queue =[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                       queue:queue
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *dataR,
                                               NSError *error) {

                               if([dataR length]>0 && error == nil)
                               {
                                   NSString *feed = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataR
                                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                   [self trythis2:dataR];

                               }
                               else if ([dataR length]==0 && error==nil)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Nothing available");
                               }
                               else if (error != nil)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Error is : %@", error);
                               }

     }]; 
}
```

Then calling the function [self trythis2:dataR]; This would call the deserialization method.

```
-(void)trythis2:(NSData*)responseData
{
    NSError *e = nil;

    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

    NSDictionary *jsonArray = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;
    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error: &e];
    //NSArray
    if (!jsonArray) {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
    } else {

        NSArray *playlistdict = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"playlist"];
        for (NSDictionary *playlistitems in playlistdict) {
            NSDictionary *videoTypes = [[playlistitems objectForKey:@"videos"] objectForKey:@"ds700"];
            NSLog(@"String: %@", videoTypes);
            for (NSDictionary *videoTypesItems in videoTypes) {
                NSLog(@"ds700 Key: %@", videoTypesItems);

                NSLog(@"Val : %@",[videoTypesItems objectForKey:@"uri"]); //error caused here


            }
        }
    }
}
```

As pointed above, the error stops at the commented line. This is my output:

```
2013-08-07 15:21:22.711 DeserializeJSON[3025:1d03] String: {
    bitrate = 700;
    length = 30;
    uri = "http://somevideo1.mp4";
}
2013-08-07 15:21:22.713 DeserializeJSON[3025:1d03] ds700 Key: bitrate
2013-08-07 15:21:22.714 DeserializeJSON[3025:1d03] -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed3e910
2013-08-07 15:21:22.715 DeserializeJSON[3025:1d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed3e910'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x33e853e7 0x3bb80963 0x33e88f31 0x33e8764d 0x33ddf208 0x72ee9 0x71fa3 0x3471c229 0x34713a89 0x3478bfe7 0x3bf9a793 0x3bf9e657 0x3bf9e7d9 0x3bfc27f1 0x3bfc2684)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

I am certain uri = "http://somevideo1.mp4"; is available but as you can see I cannot grab it. I tried making use of an NSString variable and tried assigning [videoTypesItems objectForKey:@"uri"] to it before logging it but that did not work either. Where have I gone wrong with parsing this JSON? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Why do you call a dictionary "jsonArray"??

Comment: You were doing pretty good until you got here -- `for (NSDictionary *videoTypesItems in videoTypes) {`

Comment: Hello, yes i did not intend on confusing you. And forgot to change the name before posting since i was playing around between an NSArray and an NSDictionary. Thank you for pointing that out though.

Comment: It's pretty critical, when dealing with JSON "deconstruction", to use meaningful names.

Comment: And also note that the term "nested JSON" is generally reserved for the case where the JSON structure contains a (quoted) string which itself is a valid JSON sequence.  The above is a relatively simple JSON structure, and not "nested" by that definition.

Comment: Thank you for that. I thought a nested JSON generally just involved several depths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `videoTypes` dictionary does not have any nested data. You want something like this:

```
NSDictionary *videoTypes = [[playlistitems objectForKey:@"videos"] objectForKey:@"ds700"];
NSString *url = videoTypes[@"uri"];
NSLog(@"Val: %@", uri);
```

If you really want to iterate over the keys of the dictionary, you can do:

```
NSDictionary *videoTypes = [[playlistitems objectForKey:@"videos"] objectForKey:@"ds700"];
NSLog(@"String: %@", videoTypes);
for (NSString *videoTypeKey in [videoTypes allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"ds700 Key: %@", videoTypeKey);

    NSLog(@"Val : %@", videoTypesItems[videoTypeKey]); //error caused here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, i am able to grab the URLs. Since videoTypes is currently a dictionary. Doesn't videoTypes[@"uri"] and [videoTypesItems objectForKey:@"uri"] do the same thing? Excepted the former seems to be treated like an Array?

Comment: Using `videoTypes[@"uri"]` is the modern syntax and is essentially the same as `[videoTypes objectForKey:@"uri"]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSDictionary *videoTypes = [[playlistitems objectForKey:@"videos"] objectForKey:@"ds700"];
    NSLog(@"String: %@", videoTypes);
    for (NSDictionary *videoTypesItems in videoTypes) {
        NSLog(@"ds700 Key: %@", videoTypesItems);

        NSLog(@"Val : %@",[videoTypesItems objectForKey:@"uri"]); //error caused here


    }
```

In `videoTypes`, you are opening up the "ds700" dictionary. This does not contain any child dictionaries, only key-value pairs. Your for loop however is creating a NSDictionary.

```
    "ds700": {
        "length": 30,
        "bitrate": "700",
        "uri": "http://somevideo4.mp4"
    }
```

If you would like to loop through all the different video types (ds300, ds500, ds700 and ds900), try this:

```
    NSDictionary *videoTypes = [[playlistitems objectForKey:@"videos"];
    NSLog(@"String: %@", videoTypes);
    for (NSDictionary *videoTypesItems in videoTypes) {
        NSLog(@"type Key: %@", videoTypesItems);

        NSLog(@"Val : %@",[videoTypesItems objectForKey:@"uri"]);


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, Bo A. I tried your solution, it looks like a similar solution i implemented before. And it causes the same problem.